# Issue with Discord webhook (Google form response to discord)

Tags: discord

This error always pops up on the trigger's message

```
Request failed for https://discordapp.com returned code 400. Truncated server response: {"message": "Cannot send an empty message", "code": 50006} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response).
at onSubmit(Code:53)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `"contentType": "application/json",` to your options inside the script and it should work again.